# How do I bind the same data to different options using angulajs?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to select data and bind it to a specific item, however once I select the data, all of my items are now bound to the selected data. How can I select specific data to each of my items.

here is my demo.
http://play.ionic.io/app/cb25b106e671

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a mapping data structure to save selection for each day. There can be better way but quite simply it can be like this

```
  $scope.data = {
     "Monday": {workout: ''},
     "Tuesday": {workout: ''},
     "Wednesday": {workout: ''},
     "Thursday": {workout: ''},
     "Friday": {workout: ''},
     "Saturday": {workout: ''},
     "Sunday": {workout: ''}
  }
```

and you also need to track the current day selected so you can map the selected workout to that `currentDay` key.

So first, set curretDay when you open workout selector by doing this

```
    <a class="item" ng-repeat="day in days" ng-click="openModal(day.day)">{{data[day.day].workout}}
        <span class="item-note">{{day.day}}</span>
    </a>
```

and

```
$scope.openModal = function(day) {
  $scope.currentDay = day;
  $scope.modal.show();
};
```

Second, when a workout is selected you need to set it on the `currentDay` key

```
<ion-radio class="item" ng-repeat="item in workouts" ng-value="item.workout" ng-model="data[currentDay].workout">{{item.workout}}</ion-radio>
```

Here is the [complete working demo](http://play.ionic.io/app/037c45efa7ec) (based on your demo of course)